# How can I upload a file in MVC 6 web api2 using angularjs(formData)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to upload file using formdata object create in angularjs

```
 var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("imagefile", file)

    $http.post('api/upload', formdata, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } });
```

want code for c# controller code using webapi2  in mvc 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', $scope.teamLogo);
    fd.append('aa', 'a');
    $http.post('http://localhost:51815/api/upload/', fd, {
        transformRequest: saangular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    }).then(function (teamList) { });
```

in Controller

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
    {
        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        try
        {
            // Read the form data.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            // This illustrates how to get the file names.
            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
               // Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                //Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
```

use this code in js file